# simulating transfer function with python

Tags: control, python

I've been trying for quite a while to simulate a transfer function using control library on python but I keep getting the wrong result, does anyone know the reason?

This is what I get:

[image]

This is what I want:

[image]

This is the transfer function I'm trying to simulate:

[image]

Code I used in python (I just assumed that value for K)

```
s = ctl.tf('s')
K = 180
G1 = (K) * (s+0.1) / s
G2 = (1) / ((s+1)*(s+2)*(s+10))
G3 = G1*G2
t = np.linspace(0, 20, 1000) #Tempo de 0s a 20s
_, y = ctl.impulse_response(G3, t) #calculando a resposta de G1
plt.plot(t,y)
plt.xlabel('Time in seconds')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.title('Impulse response')
plt.grid()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Response is different because of different gains maybe

Comment: Well even with the gain used on the desired response it didnt work

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on [kucar's excellent answer](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/24075/9720), you have not modeled the whole system. Looking at the [block diagram reduction rules](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Control_Systems/Block_Diagrams#Simplifying_Block_Diagrams), follow item 4 "Eliminating a Feedback Loop." I'll abbreviate the diagram here:

[image: Block diagram reduction]

So you need another step, `G4`. Since you're using negative feedback, you get

```
G4 = G3/(1+G3)
```

which, with your code as-written, gives you the following plot:

[image: Impulse Response]

Had to scratch my head for a moment as to why this doesn't look like the desired output in your question, and then I realized you're plotting the **impulse response** instead of the **step response**. The impulse response is as if you tapped the system with a hammer, and you're seeing the ringing response. The step response is what's shown in your desired output, where the input is a *constant* value (instead of an *impulse*).

Using `_, y = ctl.step_response(G4, t)` with `K = 180` gives the following plot:

[image: Step Response]

Answer (score 2):

I just did a quick MATLAB check, and maybe the problem you have is due to the fact that you simulated the Open-Loop response of the system. You did not include the Feedback part of the block diagram you have given, according to your code.

The response you desire to get is probably the Closed-Loop response of the same system. So you need to use the feedback function of the same library and check if you get the result you aim to.